# Entity Framework Code First not is not reading model and creating table in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Previously,I was very good with updating the database, whenever I wanted to create a table in database, I simply used to create a model and then the command

> update-database -Verbose

and the entity framework code first takes care of the rest,Now, I've been searching hard for updating the database because it is not getting updated whenever I create a model, so, I thought of initiating the database from scratch may work, so, I deleted my __MigrationHistory table from database, deleted the Migrations folder, Enabled it again, Added initial migration, commented out what was in the up() method, and Now again updating database by using the same command (Update-database -Verbose) but no gain.

My question is that why is it not reading the model and creating a new table in the database? How do I make the command update-database work again because previously it did?

Comment: Any chance you are using DatabaseInitializers?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this code :
`static HrAndPayroll()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<HrAndPayroll>(null);
        }`

Comment: This is correct! Can you share `-Verbose` output of `Update-Database` command?

Comment: Sir, `-Verbose` is not displaying the create table query but I've created a model for that, I don't know why is it reading the model, `-Verbose` says no pending explicit migration.

Comment: Have you executed add-migration after updating your model? This will create a new migration file which contains your sql updates. And this file will then be executed by the update-database script.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for stopping by,I updated the model, I tried `add-migration` , it created the file but there is **nothing** inside the `Up()` method :(

Answer (score 2):

After you create a new model, you either have to add a migration manually before running `Update-Database` to properly alert your database that a change has occurred, or have automatic migrations enabled. You can do a manual migration by running the following in your Package Manager:

```
Add-Migration NameOfMigration
```

You can enable automatic migrations by running the following in your Package Manager:

```
Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

If you go with automatic migrations, all you need to do is run `Update-Database` and any changes to your model, including the addition of new models, will be automatically detected and added to your database.

Comment: Sir, I've already tried this one, but no gain, for the sake of argument, I again created new model `check`, added some properties into it, and simply ran the above commands, but no gain :( `update-database -Verbose` is still saying `no explicit migrations` and also when I `add-migration initial` , it created the initial migration file with **nothing** inside the `Up()` method, whereas it should have `CreateTable('check')` sql update in it..

Comment: Are you working in a multi-project environment, or a single project?

Comment: Basically, it is a single project but accessing two databases in the connection string, one is the default one and the other one my self created for entity framework code first, namely HrAndPayroll, but I'm also specifying the ´-contexttypename´ as HrAndPayroll while enabling migration but still no changes..

Comment: When using `-ContextTypeName` you need to specify the fully-qualified name of your context, including the namespace. You should be doing something like this: `-ContextTypeName MyNameSpace.MyNestedNameSpace.HrAndPayroll`.